# displaying a different background when a radio button is checked css and knockout

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I've seen some tricks to change the background color (or other css attributes) on a group of radio buttons.  Here is some html

```
<div class="myclass col-xs-3">
    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" value="one" data-bind="checked: SelectedAttributeValueId" />
</div>
<div class="myclass col-xs-3">
    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" value="two" data-bind="checked: SelectedAttributeValueId" />
</div>
<div class="myclass col-xs-3">
    <input type="radio" name="mygroup" value="three" data-bind="checked: SelectedAttributeValueId" />
</div>
```

I've tried things like:

```
.myclass input[type="radio"]:checked{
    background-color:#f2f2f2;   
}
```

and

```
.myclass :checked{
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
```

[here is a fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/jfakey/6ctL5au3/3/)  I am using knockout, so maybe this is the tool I should use to style the `<div>` elements?

All input is appreciated,  I would prefer not to use jquery or javscript here (although knockout is okay)

Comment: well setting a attribute in radio with the bg link or color and using js onchange event and getting the attrivute with event var and setting might work

Comment: Do you need these `div`'s for something else ? I can show you a CSS solution with `input` markup only

Comment: I would like to see your solution, yes.  but I do need the encapsulating `<div>` tags for bootstrap layout, and the background of these `div` tags is what I really should be manipulating.  let me know if you are still interested in posting that solution, my problem is solved now using `:checked` and `.parent()`

Comment: @USER_8675309 Please check my very simple solution. It should help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to style the radio buttons circle.
However, you can use pseudo-elements (in this case `:before`) to render a box around the radio button, then style it in CSS.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0;
}
input[type="radio"]:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: -.5em;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -.5em;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #0073ae;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked:before {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;   
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="mygroup" value="one" /><input
       type="radio" name="mygroup" value="two" /><input
       type="radio" name="mygroup" value="three"/>
```

Comment: As far as I know you cannot use pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` on elements that cannot have content (like radio buttons, checkboxes and also `<input type="text" />`). Also, your snipped shows no change in background-color in latest Firefox.

Comment: @connexo You are absolutely right. I knew that beforehand, but was confused to see that works in Chrome. But actually it should not work, as pseudo-elements should only be supported for container elements. I guess this is a chrome bug that is non-standard compliance. Firefox is doing the right thing here. The correct way would be to use the `:before` on the parent `div`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution via jquery.

```
$('[type=radio]').click(function(){ 
    if($(this).val() == "one") {
        $('.myclass').css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
    //...two...three
});
```

Comment: do this without a jquery selector, is what I meant

Comment: Why do you put in under jquery but dont want to use jquery?

Comment: because I am stupid and click on all the suggested tags.

Comment: This changes the entire `body` to yellow, not the radio button. BTW it is not possible to change the background color of radio buttons, but there are some workarounds.

Comment: background color of the div containing the radio button -- I accomplished this using knockout with a subscribe event.  deleting this post in 5 minutes unless someone gives me a better idea